# Extract n-th line from file in bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk

I would like to extract n-th line from file and save it to a new file. For example I have index.txt :

```
cat index.txt

1   AAAGCGT
2   ACGAAGT
3   ACCTTGT
4   ATAATGT
5   AGGGTGT
6   AGCCAGT
7   AGTTCGT
8   AATGCAG
9   AAAGCGT
10  ACGAAGT
```

and output should be

```
cat index.1.txt:

1   AAAGCGT
2   ACGAAGT

cat index.2.txt:

3   ACCTTGT
4   ATAATGT

cat index.3.txt:

5   AGGGTGT
6   AGCCAGT
```

And so on.. So I would like to extract form input file first 2 rows in cycle and save to new file.

Comment: First show us the code you already tried, and then maybe someone can help you with that.

Comment: sorry my code I was thinking could be something like - for i in index.txt do head -4 $i; done;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't give you exactly the names you want, but:

```
split -l 2 index.txt index.
```

seems like the easiest solution.  It will create files with names beginning with the final argument, so will get names like 'index.aa' and 'index.bb'

Comment: Assuming GNU coreutils, `split -l 2 -a 1 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.txt index.txt index.` will give the same names as in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is very easy and it works perfectly fine. @Wintermute thank you for help with naming!!

Answer (score 4):

This will work for any number of grouped lines just by changing the `2` to a `3` or whatever number you like:

```
$ awk 'NR%2==1{++i} {print > ("index." i ".txt")}' index.txt
$ ls index.?.txt
index.1.txt  index.2.txt  index.3.txt  index.4.txt  index.5.txt
$ tail index.?.txt
==> index.1.txt <==
1   AAAGCGT
2   ACGAAGT

==> index.2.txt <==
3   ACCTTGT
4   ATAATGT

==> index.3.txt <==
5   AGGGTGT
6   AGCCAGT

==> index.4.txt <==
7   AGTTCGT
8   AATGCAG

==> index.5.txt <==
9   AAAGCGT
10  ACGAAGT
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print >"index."(x+=NR%2)".txt"}' file
```

This increments x every two lines starting from 1 and then prints the line into a file with that name

```
cat index.1.txt:

1   AAAGCGT
2   ACGAAGT

cat index.2.txt:

3   ACCTTGT
4   ATAATGT

cat index.3.txt:

5   AGGGTGT
6   AGCCAGT
```

In some awks, extra parens may be required as shown below (As commented by Ed Morton)

```
awk '{print >("index."(x+=NR%2)".txt")}' file
```

Comment: Very nice solution with my favorite awk!! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: It will fail in some awks since an unparenthesized expression on the right of output redirection is undefined behavior. You need to parenthesize the expression that creates the output file name: `print >("index."(x+=NR%2)".txt")`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

```
awk '{file=int((NR+1)/2)".txt"; print > file}' file
```

`int((NR+1)/2` maps every line number:

```
1 --> 1
2 --> 1
3 --> 2
x --> (x+1) / 2
```

So you get these files:

```
$ cat 1.txt 
1   AAAGCGT
2   ACGAAGT
```

or

```
$ cat 3.txt 
5   AGGGTGT
6   AGCCAGT
```